# Find an element and then find first from it with a certain class and inject an html in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to add error message next to the field input:

```
$("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value[0] + '</span>');
```

And the result looks, for example, like this:

```
<div class="middle">
    <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
    <span class="text-error validation-error-inline">The username has already been taken.</span>
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

However, I would like to inject the span with the message inside the `div` with the `class="right"`, so it would end up like this:

```
</div>
<div class="right">
    <span class="text-error validation-error-inline">The username has already been taken.</span>
</div>
```

How to do that? btw. one thing is important that `class="right"` could be within class="middle" to, so I somehow need to go one lebvel back in hierarchy and only then find the first `right` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this if you want to add span to the `.right` div

```
$("#" + index).closest(".middle").next(".right").empty()
.append('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value[0] + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#"+index).closest(".middle").next(".right")
    .append('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value[0] + '</span>');
```

Comment: I made that work using a combination of `parent` and `next`. I'm curious to know whether there is a reason why your solution (or mine) could be preferred?

Comment: I use `.closest` because it will still work if the HTML changes to nest the element further, so it's a little safer than depending on specific parent-child relationships.